# PHPickerViewController's Cancel Button is not working in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios15, phpickerviewcontroller

I am using `PHPickerViewController` to pick Image for User Profile Picture Purpose in iOS 15. I am using UIKit framework. I have the following code:

```swift
var pickerConfig = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
pickerConfig.selectionLimit = 1
pickerConfig.filter = .images
let pickerView = PHPickerViewController(configuration: pickerConfig)
pickerView.delegate = self
self.present(pickerView, animated: true)
```

The Picker is working properly for selecting images and delegating the results. But, when the `Cancel` button is pressed, nothing happens and the Picker is not dismissed as expected.

How to dismiss the `PHPickerViewController` instance when its own `Cancel` button is pressed ?

**Edit:**

The implementation of `PHPickerViewControllerDelegate` Method is as follows:

```swift
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult])
    {
        results.first?.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [unowned self] reading , error in
            guard let image = reading as? UIImage, error == nil else
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
                    self.profilePictureHasError = true
                    self.toggleDoneButtonEnabled()
                }
                return
            }
            self.profilePictureHasError = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                picker.dismiss(animated: true)
                self.profilePictureHasChanged = self.userProfilePicture != image
                if self.profilePictureHasChanged
                {
                    self.profilePictureView.image = image
                    self.toggleDoneButtonEnabled()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to dismiss the picker yourself in the `picker(_:didFinishPicking:)` delegate method which is called when the user completes a selection **or** when they tap the cancel button.

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontrollerdelegate/3606609-picker) for `picker(_:didFinishPicking:)`:

> The system doesn’t automatically dismiss the picker after calling this method.

For example:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    // Do something with the results here
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Your current delegate code only calls `picker.dismiss` when the results array is non-empty (i.e when the user has selected images).  When the cancel button is tapped, the delegate method is called with an empty results array.

Fix the issue by adding the following to the top of the code in your delegate method:

```
if results.isEmpty {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    return
}
```

Comment: I have done this already. My problem is that the "Cancel" button shown on the picker is not working.

Comment: Can you add the code in your `picker(_:didFinishPicking:)` delegate method to your question?  This method is also called when the cancel button is pressed (just with an empty results array).

Comment: I have updated the answer.  The current code in your delegate method only calls dismiss when the results array is non-empty, you also need to call dismiss when the results array is empty, which is the case when the user taps cancel.